# Perl and Catalyst: accessing maketext from a model

Tags: perl, internationalization, catalyst

Edited to clarify / reflect what I've been trying:

I'm using CatalystX::I18N::* in order to be able to internationalise my site.  I have that working nicely, and my site text is coming from `$c->maketext()`.

However, I've been trying to access these codes from my database model (in order to generate, e.g., success or failure messages when checking input before creating / updating) and am struggling.

According to the [CatalystX::I18N docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/CatalystX::I18N), [CatalystX::I18N::Maketext](https://metacpan.org/pod/CatalystX::I18N::Maketext) is a 'Helpful wrapper around [Locale::Maketext](https://metacpan.org/pod/Locale::Maketext). Can also be used outside of Catalyst'.

I have MyApp::Maketext setup as directed:

```perl
package MyApp::Maketext;

use strict;
use warnings;
use parent qw(CatalystX::I18N::Maketext);

1;
```

I have a little test script running, the setup for which is this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
use TopTable::Maketext;
use Path::Class::Dir;

my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new( "$Bin/..", "root", "locale" );
TopTable::Maketext->load_lexicon(
  locales => ["en_GB"], # Required
  directories => [$dir], # Required
  gettext_style => 0, # Optional, Default 1
);
```

I am then trying two different ways to get a handle to the `maketext()` method:

```perl
my $lang = TopTable::Maketext->get_handle;
printf "%s\n", $lang->maketext( "menu.title.news" );
```

Gives the following result:

```
Can't call method "maketext" on an undefined value at bin\maketext-demo.pl line 23.
```

If I swap `->get_handle` to `->new`:

```perl
my $lang = TopTable::Maketext->new;
printf "%s\n", $lang->maketext( "menu.title.news" );
```

I get the following:

```
maketext doesn't know how to say:
menu.title.news
as needed at bin\maketext-demo.pl line 23.
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to try next!  Thank you so much in advance for any pointers anyone can give.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally got my head around this - this is the code that eventually worked:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
use Data::Dumper::Concise;
use TopTable::Maketext;
use Config::ZOMG;
use Path::Class::Dir;

my $tt_config = Config::ZOMG->new( name => 'TopTable' );
my $config_hash = $tt_config->load;

my (@locales, %inhertiance, $config);
$config = $config_hash->{I18N}{locales};
foreach my $locale (keys %$config) {
  push(@locales, $locale);
  $inhertiance{$locale} = $config->{$locale}{inherits} if defined $con
+fig->{$locale}{inherits};
}

my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new( "$Bin/..", "root", "locale" );
TopTable::Maketext->load_lexicon(
  locales => \@locales,
  directories => [$dir],
  gettext_style => 1,
  inheritance => \%inhertiance,
);

my $lang = TopTable::Maketext->get_handle( "en_GB" );
printf "%s\n", $lang->maketext( "menu.title.league-tables", "Division Three" );

1;
```

This gives the correct value of:

```
League Tables for Division Three
```

Thanks for putting up with my spam!