# Adding CatalystX::I18N::Maketext to my DBIC schema

Tags: perl, internationalization, moose, catalyst

sorry, I thought I had got there after [my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790346/perl-and-catalyst-accessing-maketext-from-a-model), however I only got as far as accessing from a separate PL file.  I'm now trying to ensure I can load the lexicon with the schema load and not everytime I call a method in my result / resultset classes (which seems like a really terrible idea).

So to try and give a complete picture, here's the script I eventually got to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
use Data::Dumper::Concise;
use TopTable::Maketext;
use Config::ZOMG;
use Path::Class::Dir;

# Load the Catalyst config
my $tt_config = Config::ZOMG->new( name => "TopTable" );
my $config_hash = $tt_config->load;

# Load the locales from the config
my (@locales, %inheritance, $config);
$config = $config_hash->{I18N}{locales};
foreach my $locale (keys %$config) {
  push(@locales, $locale);
  $inheritance{$locale} = $config->{$locale}{inherits} if defined $config->{$locale}{inherits};
}

# Get the directory where the messages are defined
my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new( "$Bin/..", "root", "locale" );

# Load the lexicon
TopTable::Maketext->load_lexicon(
  locales => \@locales,
  directories => [$dir],
  gettext_style => 1,
  inheritance => \%inheritance,
);

my $lang = TopTable::Maketext->get_handle( "en_GB" );
printf "%s\n", $lang->maketext( "menu.title.league-tables", "Division Three" );

1;
```

Here's my TopTable::Maketext:

```
package TopTable::Maketext;

use strict;
use warnings;
use parent qw(CatalystX::I18N::Maketext);

1;
```

Now here's my schema file:

```
use utf8;
package TopTable::Schema;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07037 @ 2013-12-03 11:04:44
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:uMxbZipkwEqVJYByeZhY5Q


# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable(inline_constructor => 0);
1;
```

I'm very much a Moose novice I'm afraid, but believed if I added a 'lang' attribute with a builder method that sets all that up, I could then access that from my DB methods:

```
use utf8;
package TopTable::Schema;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07037 @ 2013-12-03 11:04:44
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:uMxbZipkwEqVJYByeZhY5Q

use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use TopTable::Maketext;

has "lang" => (
  is => "ro",
  isa => "TopTable::Maketext",
  builder => "_set_maketext",
  required => 1,
);

sub _set_maketext {
  my ( $self ) = @_;
  my $class = $self->class;
  my $app = $self->_app;
  my (@locales, %inheritance);
  my $config = $app->config->{I18N}{locales};
  $app->log->debug( sprintf( "app: %s, class: %s", $app, $class ) );
  printf( "app: %s, class: %s", $app, $class );
  
  foreach my $locale (keys %$config) {
    push(@locales, $locale);
    $inheritance{$locale} = $config->{$locale}{inherits} if defined $config->{$locale}{inherits};
  }

  my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new( "$Bin/..", "root", "locale" );
  TopTable::Maketext->load_lexicon(
    locales => \@locales,
    directories => [$dir],
    gettext_style => 1,
    inheritance => \%inheritance,
  );
  
  return TopTable::Maketext->get_handle( "en_GB" );
}

# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable(inline_constructor => 0);
1;
```

This however, doesn't work - the 'lang' method is accessible, but returns undef - I have added this as a test in one of my resultset methods:
`$logger->( "debug", $self->result_source->schema->lang->maketext("menu.title.league-tables", "Division Three") );`
But this gives an error:
`[error] Caught exception in TopTable::Controller::Admin::Bans->process_form "Can't call method "maketext" on an undefined value at D:\Personal\Dev\Web\www.mkttl.co.uk\TopTable\lib/TopTable/Schema/ResultSet/Ban.pm line 88."`

Grateful for any advice, thanks so much!  I hope I've provided enough to see what's going on.

Comment: Is this for a Catalyst app, or just fort he Schema? (I've not seen this module before, but I am intrigued and would like to learn more about it).

Comment: Thanks for replying!  Just the schema - I have it working from the controllers in the app, just need to try and call `->maketext` from the result / resultset methods (without resorting to setting up the lexicon every time I call the method).

Comment: How does that work? Do you store the keys to translations in the database? I'm wondering if rather than doing the lookup attached to the RS, would it make more sense to build something that translates them later on when they are on the way out.

Comment: No, the keys are in a dir structure stored in my conf - for example:  

/var/www/TopTable/root/locale  
-> enGB.po  
-> fr.po  

For the Catalyst app itself, directories are stored in the conf:  
<Model::Maketext>  
  class       TopTable::Maketext  
  directories ____path_to(root,locale)____  
</Model::Maketext>  

I'm only really looking to translate messages back that either Catalyst (or something else if something else were calling it can report back - i.e., 'Your password fields don't match') if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, struggling to format the comments properly - hope this makes sense!

Comment: So instead of making your model return `menu.title.league-tables`, you want to return the translated string behind this?

Comment: As an aside, when I worked on a larger e-com site that used gettext, we found using the native language (German, in our case) text as message ids rather than making them up. Made reading templates much easier.

Comment: Yes, exactly - the return text should be, e.g., "League Tables for Division Three".  
  
I like the native language suggestion actually, but it will take me *ages* to change - I might put it on the to-do list though!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241354/discussion-between-simbabque-and-chris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have, with the very kind and patient assistance of @simbabque, managed to work this out.

simbabque suggested I set the lang attribute to lazy, which did work:

```perl
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use TopTable::Maketext;

has "lang" => (
  is => "ro",
  isa => "TopTable::Maketext",
  builder => "_set_maketext",
  lazy => 1,
);

sub _set_maketext {
  my ( $self ) = @_;
  my $class = $self->class;
  my $app = $self->_app;
  my (@locales, %inheritance);
  my $config = $app->config->{I18N}{locales};
  $app->log->debug( sprintf( "app: %s, class: %s", $app, $class ) );
  printf( "app: %s, class: %s", $app, $class );
  
  foreach my $locale (keys %$config) {
    push(@locales, $locale);
    $inheritance{$locale} = $config->{$locale}{inherits} if defined $config->{$locale}{inherits};
  }

  my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new( "$Bin/..", "root", "locale" );
  TopTable::Maketext->load_lexicon(
    locales => \@locales,
    directories => [$dir],
    gettext_style => 1,
    inheritance => \%inheritance,
  );
  
  return TopTable::Maketext->get_handle( "en_GB" );
}
```

This worked, but produced the message `Lexicon has already been loaded for TopTable::Maketext`, which suggested Catalyst loading the lexicon was a global action, so actually I was able to get the `_set_maketext` method down to:

```perl
sub _set_maketext {
  return TopTable::Maketext->get_handle( "en_GB" );
}
```

So far so good, but I then had to work out how to get the user's locale into the call to `get_handle()`.

Again, with the help of simbabque, I have managed to get this working using an `ACCEPT_CONTEXT` sub in the model (note the `if ref( $c ) eq "TopTable"` check - as the comment says, the model seems to get called by Catalyst as part of the instantiation, before my code kicks in, and in these cases, $c is the string "TopTable", not a ref to the TopTable object so we can't call `->locale` on it):

```perl
package TopTable::Model::DB;

use strict;
use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->config(
    schema_class => 'TopTable::Schema',
    
    connect_info => {
        dsn => 'dbi:mysql:toptable',
        user => '',
        password => '',
    }
);

use TopTable::Maketext;

sub ACCEPT_CONTEXT {
  my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
  
  # We have to check the ref of $c here because this model seems to get called by Catalyst as part of the instantiation, before my code kicks in
  # and in these cases, $c is the string "TopTable", not a ref to the TopTable object.
  $self->schema->_set_maketext( TopTable::Maketext->get_handle( $c->locale ) ) if ref( $c ) eq "TopTable";
  return $self;
}

1;
```

I've changed the schema thus:

```perl
use TopTable::Maketext;

has "lang" => (
  is => "ro",
  isa => "TopTable::Maketext",
  writer => "_set_maketext",
);
```

This is now working as expected and simbabque's help was invaluable!